# Ansible playbook to add local account on IOS device if missing

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create an Ansible playbook for Cisco IOS device to check if a local user account exists on the device. If it exist do nothing, but if its not there, I want to add it.

Below is what I have but I need help with the conditional check i.e. what is the best way to check the register value, if rsitadmin is present in it do nothing, else send this command to the device username {{user}} secret {{pass}}.

Task Add RSITADMIN if missing doesn't work but is the summary of what I want to check.

I tried this jinja template as well with src parameter but didn't help.

```
{% if 'rsitadmin' in ACCOUNT %}
{% else %}
 username {{user}} secret {{pass}}
{% endif %}
```

```
---
- name: Add RSITADMIN Account if missing
  hosts: LAB
  vars_files:
    - rsitadmin.yml
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: Check if RSITADMIN account exist
      ios_command:
        commands: sh run | s username rsitadmin
      register: ACCOUNT

    - name: Print RSITADMIN account details
      debug:
          var=ACCOUNT.stdout

    - name: Add RSITADMIN if missing
      ios_config:
        lines: username {{user}} secret {{pass}}
      when: "'rsitadmin' in ACCOUNT"
```

Comment: changed_when: "'rsitadmin' not in ACCOUNT.stdout"

Comment: Sorry... misspelled..did you try.. when: "'rsitadmin' not in ACCOUNT.stdout ??

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
    - name: Configure RSITADMIN Account on devices its missing
      ios_config:
        lines:
          - username {{user}} secret {{pass}}
        save_when: changed
      when: ACCOUNT.stdout[0] is not search ("username rsitadmin")
```